# What does error 0xC02020C4 mean in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I get this error with this description.
Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4. 
The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). 
The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Did you look at the error messages above that one?

Comment: Does the follwing MSDN thread help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/d6d52157-0270-4200-a8c2-585fa9a0eed5/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve DTS\_E\_OLEDBERROR. in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381023/how-to-resolve-dts-e-oledberror-in-ssis)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the associated error message is "*The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0x{%errCode2}.*" Which should have been in a previous log message.  Of course then you will want to get %errCode2, and translate it to an error message that should have been even earlier than that in the log messages.  This could go back a ways.

The easiest approach is to turn all of the logging on, run it to the failure and the check the logs going backwards until you find the original generating exception.

Answer (score 0):

This error may mean that you are loading too many rows at once for the buffer. In the Properties for the Data Flow Task, please try increasing the number for the DeafultBufferMaxRows. This solved this error for me.

Comment: This works a bit in that it changes the rows that get imported slightly, as to your changes. You might also set it down from 10000 to 500 and get slightly more rows imported until the error will still be thrown. That is why I doubt that this is a fix for bigger tables. For me, it turned out to be a data type problem, see [How to fix SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED 0xC0202009 and DTS_E_OLEDBERROR 0x80004005 that are always thrown together as the two errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78176256/11154841).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this a misleading error, its a (multiple) source failure that is caused by a destination failure. I fixed / deleted the one destination that was failing and all the sources errors disappeared.
This was a 14 tab excel book that I had as a source and one of the destinations had a type error but it was showing 8 or so sources failing with different amounts of rows transferred each run.