# what is Unspecified error in ssis

Tags: sql-server, oledb, ssis

The ssis package consists of OLED source and OLEDB destination.Extract data from a sql 2000 server source db and load it into same database target database table.while loading 4 million rows,got error after 3 million rows..
it took 4 hours to load these many records using ssis...
please see the below error

[Ae_Data [737]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

[Ae_Data [737]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (750)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (750)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve DTS\_E\_OLEDBERROR. in ssis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381023/how-to-resolve-dts-e-oledberror-in-ssis)

Answer (score 1):

try changing it to a ADO.NET Destination

Comment: do you mean,if ado.net being use then thre would be a connection pooling and this would not happen?

Comment: The Data volume you are discribing can be to much OLEDB to take and the operation times out.  If posible change both the Source And destination adaptors to ADO Net should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and non of the internet posts worked for me.  The error I was getting to is similar to yours.  I'm posting in case someone else has the same problem

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at Get fresh data, OLE DB Destination [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Get fresh data, OLE DB Destination [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Get fresh data, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

This was happening when doing an OLE DB transfer from one table to another.  The problem was with the destination's table index

Tried to drill down on a particular record that was giving the problem and identified which fields were giving the problems.  I managed to do through a number of trial and errors.  By amending the source sql query to select different fields, until I found out which field(s) were giving me the insert problems.

Then deleted any associated indexes on that particular destination and it worked