# How to fix SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED 0xC0202009 and DTS_E_OLEDBERROR 0x80004005 that are always thrown together as the two errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I've seen many posts about this error, the difference is that i'm having this error some days yes, some days no and I can't establish a relation to anything. If I re-run the SSIS package inmediatly after the error it usually works ok.

I've changed the sql driver, as I saw on many posts related to this error, but it doesn't work.

So... this is the case: each time the SSIS package fails I'm having 2 error messages

> **Error1**: -1073450952: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "XXXX" (30) returned error code
> 0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
> engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
> defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
> stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
> with more information about the failure.
>
> **Error2**: -1071636471: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
> available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". An
> OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
> Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link
> failure".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
> Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP
> Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host. ".

[image]

Comment: Might be hardware related issue  - Eg. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/08/understanding-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host-errors-caused-by-toe-chimney.aspx

Comment: When I got this it indicated the destination disk had run out of space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve DTS\_E\_OLEDBERROR. in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381023/how-to-resolve-dts-e-oledberror-in-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue is fairly common and practically impossible to track down and eliminate.

I would initiate the SSIS Package from a SQL Server Agent Job.  In the Job Step definition I would set it to retry e.g. 3 times with a 5 minute delay.

Comment: Thks Mike; it's strange, but in most of the cases the job fails, I've got the email with error code but in the Job Activity Monitor it is running (believe me, I've refreshed the screen :) ) So, the retry option is not working here. I did that some days ago and, as the job appears to be running, the server never retry

Comment: I would check in the Job History window - there you can see if the running job has failed and is retrying.

Comment: Just for the record... Mike, your solution works fine in most of the cases. Sometimes the SQL Server misses the situation of "Job failed" and it keeps the job as "running" on the agent. That's where the job will not start again. In other cases, it will work.. so.. partially solved. Thank you

Comment: Is this SQL 2012 using the Package Catalog architecture?

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly a **concurrency** issue.  I had a package where I read from a source table, then read from the destination table, then did some transformations, and finally the survivors got updated in the destination table.  Depending on how many steps are between, how intricate the logic is, and what network traffic is like that day, the process may reach different checkpoints on different days before locking up.

I found from the Activity Monitor that my write was waiting for the rest of the rows.  What it didn't tell me was that my read was blocked by the table-lock on the write.  I forced a **blocking operation** by inserting a client-side sort between the read and the write.  Other possible solutions involve **writing to a temp table**; turning off the **table-lock** on the destination write; **redoing the logic** so that you don't need the destination; or splitting them up into different Data Flow Tasks and enforcing execution order with **precedence arrows**.

If you're doing an "upsert" (insert or update) operation, try using a pattern similar to what's described here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/62063/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my package. My source is mySql database so I am using .Net providers. MySql Provider. And during the import after around 30 k records I have error in my source block:

> Error1: -1073450952: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on component "XXXX" (30) returned error code 0xC0202009. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I fixed it with changes in advanced option for that connection manager (MySql Provider):

I set `value = 10` for `keep alive` and I increased connection timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to the source is corrupted. We had this situation, too. In our case, the source was a log shipping server and when the package was trying to make a connection to the server, it forcibly closed the connection since it was in the middle of a backup/restore action. So we changed the time of connecting to server to avoid this failure. Another case this issue came up was related  to network problems and mostly by connecting to admin team the problem resolved.