# TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, tcp, ssis, business-intelligence

Sometimes during loading data in SSIS from SQL Server to SQL Server 2016 (using Data Flow) I get following errors:

> SE [[209]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error
>   has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Communication link failure". An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout
>   period has expired. ".
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SE failed the pre-execute phase and returned
>   error code 0xC0202009.

I cannot find any pattern when I get this. Anyone had the same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this elusive problem before and searched for it, the only notion on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bea48b89-0fec-4339-be0b-5eb1073b9558/ssis-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices) and [SO question "how to resolve DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. in ssis"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381023/how-to-resolve-dts-e-oledberror-in-ssis). In a nutshell - issue is related to high load of SQL server or its runtime environment. In my case, error disappeared after adding more RAM to SQL server and configuring TCP window = 32767; however, I am not convinced it was the cure.

Comment: You meant adding RAM to which SQL Server? Source or SSIS instance?

Comment: @Testtest11, in my case RAM was added to SQL server which provided data to SSIS.